# GoogleアシスタントからAndroidアプリを起動する方法について

Tags: android

Googleアシスタントアプリで「Facebookアプリを起動して」や「Twitterアプリを起動して」と言うとアプリが起動してきます。
該当アプリがインストールされていない場合は、Playストアへの導線が表示されるかと思います。

質問ですが、自作のAndroidアプリをGoogleアシスタントから起動させるにはどのようにしたら良いでしょうか？

Googleアシスタントからどのようにアプリを起動しているか、仕組みについての説明も合わせて教えて頂けると助かります。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 何か登録いるみたいですよ。 https://developers-jp.googleblog.com/2017/10/google-assistant-app-ja.html

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。上記URLを確認しましたが、Googleアシスタントアプリ内でアプリを動かす方法に見えます。私が試したいのは単にGoogleアシスタントアプリから自作のAndroidアプリを起動させたいです(Googleアシスタントアプリは裏にまわり、自作のAndroidアプリが起動する)。

Answer (score 1):

同じように ****を起動して でできると思われます
仕組みは****のアプリ名(またはそれに近いもの、よみが同じもの)のIntentを飛ばしている感じだと思います